# Filter parent div with only one type of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to search for divs with class '**test**' that has only button type inside hid childs or child nodes. This is the HTML that I have to filter.

```
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <button> <span>Button 1</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <button> <span>Button 2</span></button>
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Based on [this](https://api.jquery.com/only-of-type-selector/) jQuery selector I've been testing on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7xus7n0/1/) but it returns me this error: [image: this error]

The div that I've been expecting to return is the first div.
So how can I reach it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the length of child div elements and child div elements that have button elements in it:

```
var notButtonDivs = $('.test').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('div').length == $(this).find('div:has(button)').length
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdbuj5rr/)**

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick.

```
var TestDivs = $(document).find(".test div button");
alert(TestDivs[0].innerHTML);
```